# Fallback method is not called in @HystrixCommand

Tags: java, junit, hystrix, circuit-breaker

Trying to test my fallback method, but unfortunately it is never called :( 
Certain class calls method like this:

```
@Service
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class ServiceOne
{

    @Inject
    private HystrixService hystrixService;

    public String callCommand(int id, String name)
    {
        return hystrixService.callCommand(id, name);
    }

}
```

This is how my HystrixService looks like:

```
@Service
public class HystrixService 
{

    @Inject
    private ServiceTwo serviceTwo;

    @Override
    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallback")
    public String callCommand(final int id, final String name)
    {
        return serviceTwo.callMethod(id, name);
    }


    public String fallback(final int id, final String name)
    {
        return "blablabla";
    }
}
```

My test:

```
//class
@Inject
@Spy
private ServiceTwo serviceTwo;

@Inject
@Spy
private ServiceOne serviceOne;


@Test
public void test_fallBack()
{
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(serviceTwo).callMethod(1,
                "name");
    String res = serviceOne.callCommand(1, "name");
}
```

Why does my serviceOne never return stub "blablabla", it constantly throws RuntimeException and never goes to fallback method. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try to add @EnableHystrix annotation ?

Comment: Added below @EnableCircuitBreaker. Didn't help

Comment: Or try to remove annotation @spy from your service one

Comment: @MartinChoraine didn't help

Comment: But did you succeed to make it work without test ?